# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined In Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material

Error Message on console of post-create.component.html

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at PostCreateComponent_Template (template.html:13)

I think the problem is here at console.log(form.value.title, form.value.content);

post-create.component.html

```
<mat-card>
  <form (submit)="onAddPost(postform)" #postform="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        name="title"
        [ngModel]="post.title"
        required
        #title="ngModel"
        placeholder="Enter Post Title"
      />
      <mat-error *ngIf="title.invalid">Please enter a post title.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <textarea
        matInput
        rows="6"
        name="content"
        [ngModel]="post.content"
        required
        #content="ngModel"
        placeholder="Enter Post Content"
      ></textarea>
      <mat-error *ngIf="content.invalid">Please enter a post title.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Add Post</button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

post-create.component.ts (the ts file for the above html file ) please check and help me with the error message thanks in advance!!!

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from "@angular/router";
import { Posts } from "../post.model";
import { PostService } from "../post.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-post-create",
  templateUrl: "./post-create.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./post-create.component.css"],
})
export class PostCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public postservice: PostService, public route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  private postId: string;
  private mode = "create";

  post: Posts;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      if (paramMap.has("postId")) {
        console.log(paramMap.get("postId"));
        this.mode = "edit";
        this.postId = paramMap.get("postId");

        this.post = this.postservice.getPosts(this.postId);
        console.log(this.post);
      } else {
        this.mode = "create";
        this.postId = null;
      }
    });
  }

  onAddPost(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.mode === "create") {
      console.log(form.value.title, form.value.content);
      this.postservice.addPosts(form.value.title, form.value.content);
    } else {
      this.postservice.updatePost(
        this.postId,
        form.value.title,
        form.value.content
      );
    }
    // this.postservice.addPosts(form.value.title, form.value.content);
    form.resetForm();
  }
}
```

Comment: is getPosts() makes an ajax call?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti console.log(form.value.title, form.value.content); //outputs undefined

Comment: what is returned from `this.postservice.getPosts(this.postId)`?

Comment: @izmaylovdev this.postservice.getPosts(this.postId) this works fine.. problem is that this returns console.log(form.value.title, form.value.content); //outputs undefined

Comment: Your error is not related to the form value at all. `post` is undefined, here is an error come from.

Answer (score 2):

When you use ngModel with an object property like you did here `[ngModel]="post.title"` you have to initialize the object with an empty object on its declaration or in the class constructor, or in the ngOnInit method.
So, something like this `post: Posts = { title: null, content: null };` will probably solve the issue.

Comment: what you are talking about post: Posts = { title: null, content: null } had been done in post.model file

Comment: But you're not initializing your post attribute inside PostCreateComponent class with this value, you have to do it.